# Update item in tree structure by reference and return updated tree structure

Tags: functional-programming, tree, ramda.js, hyperapp

I am currently learning functional programming using HyperappJS (V2) and RamdaJS. My first project is a simple blog app where users can comment on posts or other comments. The comments are represented as a tree structure.

My state looks something like this:

```
// state.js
export default {
    posts: [
        {
            topic: `Topic A`, 
            comments: []
        },
        {
            topic: `Topic B`, 
            comments: [
                {
                    text: `Comment`, 
                    comments: [ /* ... */ ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            topic: `Topic C`, 
            comments: []
        }
    ],
    otherstuff: ...
}
```

When the user wants to add a comment I pass the current tree item to my addComment-action. There I add the comment to the referenced item and return a new state object to trigger the view update.

So, currently I'm doing this and it's working fine:

```
// actions.js
import {concat} from 'ramda'   
export default {
    addComment: (state, args) => {
        args.item.comments = concat(
            args.item.comments, 
            [{text: args.text, comments: []}]
        )
        return {...state}
    }
}
```

My question: Is this approach correct? Is there any way to clean up this code and make it more functional? What I am looking for would be something like this:

```
addComment: (state, args) => ({
    ...state,
    posts: addCommentToReferencedPostItemAndReturnUpdatedPosts(args, state.posts)
})
```

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but is it better to keep it in tree structure compare to flat structure?
`[{topic: 'One', id: 1, comments: [{id: 2, text: ''}]}, {comments: [{}], parentId: 2}]` as example. I don't know all your business requirements, but it could be harder to update all this nested structure.

Answer (score 5):

Ramda is intentionally designed not to modify user data.  Passing something by reference won't help; Ramda will still refuse to alter it.

One alternative is to see if you can pass the *path* to the node to which you want to add the comment.  Ramda can use a `path` with [`lensPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensPath) and [`over`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) to make a version that will return a new `state` object, something like this:

```js
const addComment = (state, {text, path}) => 
  over (
    lensPath (['posts', ...intersperse ('comments', path), 'comments']), 
    append ({text, comments: []}), 
    state
  )

const state = {
  posts: [
    {topic: `Topic A`, comments: []},
    {topic: `Topic B`, comments: [{text: `Comment`, comments: [
      {text: 'foo', comments: []}
      // path [1, 0] will add here
    ]}]},
    {topic: `Topic C`, comments: []}
  ],
  otherstuff: {}
}

console .log (
  addComment (state, {path: [1, 0], text: 'bar'})
)
//=> {
//   posts: [
//     {topic: `Topic A`, comments: []},
//     {topic: `Topic B`, comments: [{text: `Comment`, comments: [
//       {text: 'foo', comments: []}, 
//       {text: 'bar', comments: []}
//     ]}]},
//     {topic: `Topic C`, comments: []}
//   ],
//   otherstuff: {}
// }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {over, lensPath, intersperse, append} = R            </script>
```

Here the path we use is `[1, 0]`, representing the second post (index 1) and the first comment (index 0) within it.

We could write more a more sophisticated [lens](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens) to traverse the object if the path is not enough.

I don't know if this is an overall improvement, but it's definitely a more appropriate use of Ramda. (Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of Ramda.)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! This would certainly work but it sure feels cumbersome always having to calculate/keep a path to an object that I already have a reference to. It just seems superfluous to me.
I guess the real problem here is that hyperapp 2 does not allow a partial state update but instead requires the full state to be returned from an action.

Comment: I'm very much in favor of hyperapp's choice here: that's what any functional system likely would do.  It may simply be that Ramda is not the right tool for you here.  It's never been designed as a general-purpose utility library, only as one to make FP code easier in JS.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach where we 1) **locate** the target object in your state tree, and then 2) **transform** the located object. Let's assume that your tree has some way to `id` the individual objects -

```js
const state =
  { posts:
      [ { id: 1              // <-- id
        , topic: "Topic A"
        , comments: []
        }
      , { id: 2              // <-- id
        , topic: "Topic B"
        , comments: []
        }
      , { id: 3              // <-- id
        , topic: "Topic C"
        , comments: []
        }
      ]
  , otherstuff: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  }
```

**search**

You could start by writing a generic `search` which yields the possible path(s) to a queried object -

```js
const search = function* (o = {}, f = identity, path = [])
{ if (!is (o, Object))
    return

  if (f (o))
    yield path

  for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries(o))
    yield* search (v, f, [ ...path, k ])
}
```

Let's locate all objects where `id` is greater than `1` -

```js
for (const path of search (state, ({ id = 0 }) => id > 1))
  console .log (path)

// [ "posts", "1" ]
// [ "posts", "2" ]
```

These "paths" point to objects in your `state` tree where the predicate, `({ id = 0 }) => id > 1)`, is true. Ie,

```js
// [ "posts", "1" ]
state.posts[1] // { id: 2, topic: "Topic B", comments: [] }

// [ "posts", "2" ]
state.posts[2] // { id: 3, topic: "Topic C", comments: [] }
```

We will use `search` to write higher-order functions like `searchById`, which encodes our intentions more clearly -

```js
const searchById = (o = {}, q = 0) =>
  search (o, ({ id = 0 }) => id === q)

for (const path of searchById(state, 2))
  console .log (path)

// [ "posts", "1" ]
```

**transform**

Next we can write `transformAt` which takes an input state object, `o`, a `path`, and a transformation function, `t`.
Using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) we plainly encode our intentions -

1. When the query, `q`, is `None`, the path has been exhausted and it's time to run the transformation, `t`, on the input object, `o`.
2. (inductive) `q` is *not* empty. If the input, `o`, is an object, using `Object.assign` create a new object where its new `q` property is a transform of its old `q` property, `o[q]`.
3. (inductive) `q` is *not* empty and `o` is *not* an object. We cannot expect to lookup `q` on a non-object, therefore `raise` an error to signal to that `transformAt` was given an invalid path.

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const transformAt =
  ( o = {}
  , [ q = None, ...path ] = []
  , t = identity
  ) =>
    q === None                                  // 1
      ? t (o)
  : is (o, Object)                              // 2
      ? Object.assign
          ( is (o, Array) ? [] : {}
          , o
          , { [q]: transformAt (o[q], path, t) }
          )
  : raise (Error ("transformAt: invalid path"))  // 3
```

Now we can easily write `appendComment` which takes an input, `state`, a comment's id, `parentId`, and a new comment, `c` -

```js
const append = x => a =>
  [ ...a, x ]

const appendComment = (state = {}, parentId = 0, c = {}) =>
{ for (const path of searchById(state, parentId))
    return transformAt   // <-- only transform first; return
      ( state
      , [ ...path, "comments" ]
      , append (c)
      )
  return state // <-- if no search result, return unmodified state
}
```

Recall `search` generates *all* possible paths to where the predicate query returns true. You have to make a choice how you will handle the scenario where a query returns more than one result. Consider data like -

```js
const otherState =
  { posts: [ { type: "post", id: 1, ... }, ... ]
  , images: [ { type: "image", id: 1, ... }, ... ]
  }
```

Using `searchById(otherState, 1)` would get *two* objects where `id = 1`. In `appendComment` we choose only to modify the *first* match. It's possible to modify *all* the `search` results, if we wanted -

```js
// but don't actually do this
const appendComment = (state = {}, parentId = 0, c = {}) =>
  Array
    .from (searchById (state, parentId)) // <-- all results
    .reduce
        ( (r, path) =>
            transformAt  // <-- transform each
              ( r
              , [ ...path, "comments" ]
              , append (c)
              )
        , state // <-- init state
        )
```

But in this scenario, we probably don't want duplicate comments in our app. Any querying function like `search` may return **zero, one, or more** results and *you* have to decide how your program responds in each scenario.

**put it together**

Here are the remaining dependencies -

```js
const is = (t, T) =>
  t?.constructor === T

const raise = e =>
  { throw e }

const identity = x =>
  x
```

Let's append our first new comment to `id = 2`, *"Topic B"* -

```js
const state1 =
  appendComment
    ( state
    , 2
    , { id: 4, text: "nice article!", comments: [] }
    )
```

Our first state revision, `state1`, will be -

```js
{ posts:
    [ { id: 1
      , topic: "Topic A"
      , comments: []
      }
    , { id: 2
      , topic: "Topic B"
      , comments:
          [ { id: 4                     //
            , text: "nice article!"     // <-- newly-added
            , comments: []              //     comment
            }                           //
          ]
      }
    , { id: 3
      , topic: "Topic C"
      , comments: []
      }
    ]
, otherstuff: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}
```

And we'll append another comment, nested on that one -

```js
const state2 =
  appendComment
    ( state
    , 4  // <-- id of our last comment
    , { id: 5, text: "i agree!", comments: [] }
    )
```

This second revision, `state2`, will be -

```js
{ posts:
    [ { id: 1, ...}
    , { id: 2
      , topic: "Topic B"
      , comments:
          [ { id: 4
            , text: "nice article!"
            , comments:
                [ { id: 5             //     nested
                  , text: "i agree!"  // <-- comment
                  , comments: []      //     added
                  }                   //
                ]
            }
          ]
      }
    , { id: 3, ... }
    ]
, ...
}
```

**code demonstration**

In this demo we will,

- create `state1` by modifying `state` to add the first comment
- create `state2` by modifying `state1` to add the second (nested) comment
- print `state2` to show the expected state
- print `state` to show that the original state is not modified

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const is = (t, T) =>
  t?.constructor === T

const raise = e =>
  { throw e }

const identity = x =>
  x

const append = x => a =>
  [ ...a, x ]

const search = function* (o = {}, f = identity, path = [])
{ if (!is (o, Object))
    return

  if (f (o))
    yield path

  for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries(o))
    yield* search (v, f, [ ...path, k ])
}

const searchById = (o = {}, q = 0) =>
  search (o, ({ id = 0 }) => id === q)

const transformAt =
  ( o = {}
  , [ q = None, ...path ] = []
  , t = identity
  ) =>
    q === None
      ? t (o)
  : is (o, Object)
      ? Object.assign
          ( is (o, Array) ? [] : {}
          , o
          , { [q]: transformAt (o[q], path, t) }
          )
  : raise (Error ("transformAt: invalid path"))

const appendComment = (state = {}, parentId = 0, c = {}) =>
{ for (const path of searchById(state, parentId))
    return transformAt
      ( state
      , [ ...path, "comments" ]
      , append (c)
      )
  return state
}

const state =
  { posts:
      [ { id: 1
        , topic: "Topic A"
        , comments: []
        }
      , { id: 2
        , topic: "Topic B"
        , comments: []
        }
      , { id: 3
        , topic: "Topic C"
        , comments: []
        }
      ]
  , otherstuff: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  }

const state1 =
  appendComment
    ( state
    , 2
    , { id: 4, text: "nice article!", comments: [] }
    )

const state2 =
  appendComment
    ( state1
    , 4
    , { id: 5, text: "i agree!", comments: [] }
    )

console.log("state2", JSON.stringify(state2, null, 2))
console.log("original", JSON.stringify(state, null, 2))
```

**immutablejs**

The techniques described above are parallel to the other (excellent) answer using lenses provided by Scott. The notable difference here is we start with an *unknown path* to the target object, find the path, then transform the state at the discovered path.

The techniques in these two answers could even be combined. `search` yields paths that could be used to create `R.lensPath` and then we could update the state using `R.over`.

And a higher-level technique is lurking right around the corner. This one comes from the understanding that writing functions like `transformAt` is reasonably complex and it's difficult to get them right. At the heart of the problem, our state object is a plain JS object, `{ ... }`, which offers no such feature as immutable updates. Nested within those object we use arrays, `[ ... ]`, that have the same issue.

Data structures like `Object` and `Array` were designed with countless considerations that may not match your own. It is for this reason why you have the ability to design your own data structures that behave the way you want. This is an often overlooked area of programming, but before we jump in and try to write our own, let's see how the Wise Ones before us did it.

One example, [ImmutableJS](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/), solves this *exact* problem. The library gives you a collection of data structures as well as functions that operate on those data structures, all of which guarantee *immutable* behaviour. Using the library is convenient -

```
const append = x => a => // ⌫ unused
  [ ...a, x ]
```

```js
const { fromJS } =
  require ("immutable")

const appendComment = (state = {}, parentId = 0, c = {}) =>
{ for (const path of searchById(state, parentId))
    return transformAt
      ( fromJS (state) // <-- 1. from JS to immutable
      , [ ...path, "comments" ]
      , list => list .push (c) // <-- 2. immutable push
      )
      .toJS () // <-- 3. from immutable to JS
  return state
}
```

Now we write `transformAt` with the expectation that it will be given an immutable structure -

```
const is = (t, T) => // ⌫ unused
  t?.constructor === T
```

```js
const { Map, isCollection, get, set } =
  require ("immutable")

const transformAt =
  ( o = Map ()             // <-- empty immutable object
  , [ q = None, ...path ] = []
  , t = identity
  ) =>
    q === None
      ? t (o)
  : isCollection (o)       // <-- immutable object?
      ? set                // <-- immutable set
          ( o
          , q
          , transformAt
              ( get (o, q) // <-- immutable get
              , path
              , t
              )
          )
  : raise (Error ("transformAt: invalid path"))
```

Hopefully we can begin to see `transformAt` as a generic function. It is not coincidence that ImmutableJS includes functions to do exactly this, `getIn` and `setIn` -

```
const None = // ⌫ unused
  Symbol ()

const raise = e => // ⌫ unused
  { throw e }
```

```js
import { Map, setIn, getIn } from "immutable"

const transformAt =
  ( o = Map () // <-- immutable Map
  , path = []
  , t = identity
  ) =>
    setIn // <-- immutable set by path
      ( o
      , path
      , t (getIn (o, path)) // <-- immutable get by path
      )
```

To my surprise, even `transformAt` is implemented *exactly* as `updateIn` -

```
const identity = x => // ⌫ unused
  x

const transformAt =  //
  ( o = Map ()       // ⌫ unused
  , path = []        //
  , t = identity     //
  ) => ...           //
```

```js
import { fromJS, updateIn } from "immutable"

const appendComment = (state = {}, parentId = 0, c = {}) =>
{ for (const path of searchById(state, parentId))
    return updateIn // <-- immutable update by path
      ( fromJS (state)
      , [ ...path, "comments" ]
      , list => list .push (c)
      )
      .toJS ()
  return state
}
```

This the lesson of higher-level data structures. By using structures designed for immutable operations, we reduce the overall complexity of our entire program. As a result, the program can now be written in less than 30 lines of straightforward code -

```js
//
// complete implementation using ImmutableJS
//
import { fromJS, updateIn } from "immutable"

const search = function* (o = {}, f = identity, path = [])
{ if (Object (o) !== o)
    return

  if (f (o))
    yield path

  for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries(o))
    yield* search (v, f, [ ...path, k ])
}

const searchById = (o = {}, q = 0) =>
  search (o, ({ id = 0 }) => id === q)

const appendComment = (state = {}, parentId = 0, c = {}) =>
{ for (const path of searchById(state, parentId))
    return updateIn
      ( fromJS (state)
      , [ ...path, "comments" ]
      , list => list .push (c)
      )
      .toJS ()
  return state
}

export { search, searchById, appendComment }
```

ImmutableJS is just *one* possible implementation of these structures. Many others exist, each with their unique APIs and trade-offs. You can pick from a pre-made library or you can custom tailor your own data structures to meet your exact needs. Either way, hopefully you can see the benefits provided by well-designed data structures and perhaps gain insight on why popular structures of today were invented in the first place.

Expand the snippet below to run the ImmutableJS version of the program in your browser -

```js
const { fromJS, updateIn } =
  Immutable

const search = function* (o = {}, f = identity, path = [])
{ if (Object (o) !== o)
    return

  if (f (o))
    yield path

  for (const [ k, v ] of Object.entries(o))
    yield* search (v, f, [ ...path, k ])
}

const searchById = (o = {}, q = 0) =>
  search (o, ({ id = 0 }) => id === q)

const appendComment = (state = {}, parentId = 0, c = {}) =>
{ for (const path of searchById(state, parentId))
    return updateIn
      ( fromJS (state)
      , [ ...path, 'comments' ]
      , list => list .push (c)
      )
      .toJS ()
  return state
}

const state =
  { posts:
      [ { id: 1
        , topic: 'Topic A'
        , comments: []
        }
      , { id: 2
        , topic: 'Topic B'
        , comments: []
        }
      , { id: 3
        , topic: 'Topic C'
        , comments: []
        }
      ]
  , otherstuff: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  }

const state1 =
  appendComment
    ( state
    , 2
    , { id: 4, text: "nice article!", comments: [] }
    )

const state2 =
  appendComment
    ( state1
    , 4
    , { id: 5, text: "i agree!", comments: [] }
    )

console.log("state2", JSON.stringify(state2, null, 2))
console.log("original", JSON.stringify(state, null, 2))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immutable@4.0.0-rc.12/dist/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is incredible and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: @subarachnid I'm delighted to help. `search` and `transformAt` are somewhat complex and this demonstrates the challenge of supporting immutable read/write on a deeply-nested state tree. A comment on your question suggests using a flat structure which has different pros and cons. It's flat, so it's easy to _write_ new changes, but _because_ it's flat, if we want to _read_ (display) it as a tree, we must first assemble it

Comment: @subarachnid I added a section at the end which hopes to unlock a higher level of thinking

Comment: Impressive (as always)! Just out of curiosity: is this the kind of use case that this [Clojure function](http://cljs.github.io/api/clojure.walk/postwalk) would typically handle?

Comment: @customcommander I don't know Clojure idioms and I know even less ClojureScript so I can't say what's typical, but yes, `postwalk` _could_ be used to modify deep state in a tree. Something like, `(postwalk (fn [x] (if (equal? (:id x) q) (append-comment x ...) x)) state)`.

Comment: `(def state '(1 (2 (3)) 4)) (postwalk (fn [id] (if (= id 3) 99 id)) state)` returns `'(1 (2 (99)) 4)`. To my understanding, Clojure and ClojureScript's data structures are all immutable, so any operations on them are guaranteed to produce _new_ values.